# Do MIP Solvers (e.g. CBC, Gurobi, ...) automatically decompose separable problems?

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming, coin-or-cbc

I have many optimization problems that I solve sequentially with `CBC`.

Alternatively, I throw all these problems into one optimization problem and just do one solve. The idea was to reduce overhead and I assumed that `CBC` automatically recognizes that the parts are separable.

The result was identical, so I did everything correct. Unfortunately, the solution time was much much higher. So my questions:

1. `CBC` does not recognize that it can separate an optimization problem?
2. Shouldn't it be easy to recognize separability in advance?
3. Does `Gurobi` do that?

Thanks four your hints!

Comment: I think you already have the answer, at least for CBC: if it has a runtime for the whole problem significantly higher than the sum of the individual problems, then it doesn't decompose (or at least it can't figure out how to decompose your problem).

Comment: For theoretical decomposition see e.g. [Benders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benders_decomposition), [Dantzig-Wolfe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dantzig%E2%80%93Wolfe_decomposition).

Comment: There are techniques to reduce overhead when solving multiple small problems. This should likely be preferred over throwing all of the spaghetti at the wall at once and seeing what sticks.

Answer (score 1):

No. Solvers don't do decomposition automatically or by default. Cplex can do Benders automatically (using an option).

The special case where all subproblems are totally independent is not so common. So solvers don't detect this and thus ignore that and solve it as one big problem. If the subproblems are related there may be different ways to achieve better speed (e.g. by updating the problem).

For many small independent problems (like in DEA problems), it may make sense to batch a few problems together (e.g. instead of 100 tiny problems, solve 10 batches of 10). This can make some difference.